# Import default in Vue component not definied in DevTools console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-modules

Simple data example, constants.js

```
export default {
  name: "John Smith",
  age: 10
};
```

Import it on the Vue component, which renders correctly. But if I use the DevTools and type `c` in the console... `c` is undefined.

```
import c from "../constants/constants.js";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  computed: {
    myName() {
      debugger;
      // In DevTools, console... c is undefined
      // even though this clearly works
      return c.name;
    },
  },
};
```

I don't understand why?

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/constantsimportreference-ud0d3e?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:90-341

https://ud0d3e.csb.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are not exposed to the global scope (`window`) when transpiled.

If you really want to expose `c` in DevTools you'd have to do `window.c = c`; Be careful when referencing window as this will break when rendering server side or prerendering as `window` does not exist.

Comment: Okay, that helped me find the right words to google. I see webpack can be configured to expose a `library` on the global object. Still wish it was a simple as I was expecting, but it makes more sense now. Thanks.